# How to test/refactor-to-test a function that calls http.ListenAndServe

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm learning go and am working on a simple service that ingests some data from a queue and sticks it in the database. It also runs a web server to allow scraping of data. Right now I have two go files (omitted some text for brevity):

```
func main() {
    parseConfig()

    s := &Service{ServiceConfig: config}
    err := s.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

And then the definition of the service (again left out some pieces for brevity):

```
func (s *Service) Run() error {

    if err := s.validate(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := s.initDB(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer s.db.Close()

    // Same pattern with health check library (init, start, close)
    // Same pattern starting queue consumer (init, start, close)

    s.mux = http.NewServeMux()
    s.registerHandlers(s.mux)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", s.mux)

    return nil
}
```

And the struct

```
type Service struct {
    Config // Hold db connection info
    db  *sql.DB
    hc  *health
}
```

I'm able to test the individual pieces fine (like `initDB` or `validate`) but I'm not unclear how one would test the `Run` function because http.ListenAndServe blocks. I eventually time out. Previously, I would use httpTest and make a test server but that was when `main` would start the server (the application was more basic at first).

Some things I would test:

That I can hit the metrics endpoint once started.
That I can hit the health endpoint once started.
That I can push a message on the queue and it is received once started.
That `Run` actually starts w/o a panic.

Some notes: I am using docker to spin up a queue and database. The point of testing the `Run` function is to ensure that the bootstrapping works and the application can run successfully. Eventually I will want to push data through the queue and assert that its been processed correctly.

Question: How should I test this or refactor it so that it is more easily testable end to end?

Comment: Instead of the convenience http.ListenAndServe construct your own https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server. Let that one ListenAndServe in a own goroutine and Shutdown it once your test is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build a test harness using a goroutine to execute `Run` in your unit test:

```
func TestRun(t *testing.T) {
    service := Service{}
    serviceRunning := make(chan struct{})
    serviceDone := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        close(serviceRunning)
        err := service.Run()            
        defer close(serviceDone)
    }()

    // wait until the goroutine started to run (1)
    <-serviceRunning

    //
    // interact with your service to test whatever you want
    //

    // stop the service (2)
    service.Shutdown()

    // wait until the service is shutdown (3)
    <-serviceDone
}
```

This is just a basic example to show how it could be done in principle. There are several points that should be improved for use in production:

(0) The most important detail: **Do not use `http.ListenAndServe` in production!** Create your own instance of `http.Server` instead. This saves you a lot of trouble.

```
s.httpServer := http.Server {
    Addr: ":8080",
    Handler: s.mux,
}
```

(1) The indication that the service is running should be moved into your `Service` type. The initialization part in `Run` might take a while and the indication channel should be closed right before `ListenAndServe` is called:

```
close(s.Running)
s.httpServer.ListenAndServe()
```

Of course, you need to add the indication channel to your Service type.

(2) Add a `Shutdown` method to `Service` that calls `s.httpServer.Shutdown()`. This will cause the call to `s.httpServer.ListenAndServe` to return with the error `http.ErrServerClosed`.

```
if err := s.httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
    return err
}
return nil
```

It is important to shutdown your service at the end of the test. Otherwise you will not be able to have more than one unit test for your service. And it is good citizenship anyway to clean up the resources.

(3) You need to wait until `service.Run` returned to make sure that the service is actually shutdown.

Comment: Hello :) thanks for this answer but let's get deeper! Taking in consideration I want `ListenAndServer` (while unit testing) to fall within the if condition. By shutting down the API, I won't false into it because of the condition `err != http.ErrServerClosed`. Is there any way to create a situation (over unit test) to make `ListenAndServe` to return another error? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course. You can for example try to open a port that is already in use. This will make the Listen part fail. For more inspiration you can have a look at https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.3:src/net/http/server.go;l=2918;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.3

Answer (score 1):

The httptest package comes with a test server built for this purpose.

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#example-Server